# Замета символа на тег <br/> в строке

Tags: jquery

Приветствую!

Стоит такая задача: Поменять разделитель между именем и должностью на тег `<br/>`

Сейчас есть такой скрипт, но он не корректно работает, если на странице присутствует такой же

Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
var el = $('.analytics_author_name');
    el.html(el.html().replace("|", "<br/>"));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zc6cvt2a/

Answer (score 3):

Метод [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) может принимать функцию, первый параметр, которой индекс элемента в выборке, а второй - текущее значение свойства `innerHTML`

Вернуть нужно новое значение для свойства.

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```js
var el = $('.analytics_author_name');
el.html((index, oldHtml) => oldHtml.replace("|", "<br/>"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="analytics_author_name">John Doe | manager</div>
<div class="analytics_author_name">Bill Geyts | CEO</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!